# Is there concurrency in smartcontracts?

Tags: solidity, concurrency

I have a question about concurrency in smart contracts. For instance, I have array of `struct`s and each struct should have a "unqiue" ID. For my needs, it is enough to have ID equal to position in array (later it can be changed, so ID must be stored in structure instance).

Is it safe to get array length to use it as ID or many transaction could be handled in the same time and get the same array length?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no concurrency in smart contracts. You don't need to worry about race conditions, since transactions are processed in blocks sequentially with no concurrency.